# Transform .docx document generated with PhpOffice\PhpWord\TemplateProcessor to .odt format

Tags: php, laravel, phpword, odt

We generate documents using PhpOffice\PhpWord\TemplateProcessor's templates. Now client wants to change format to .odt.

How can we do that without rewriting the whole function, or at least using a similar template approach (we create a word with variables and then programatically fill it with values from the database)?

TemplateProcessor seems to only work with .docx documents.

```
 \PhpOffice\PhpWord\Settings::setOutputEscapingEnabled(true);
 $doc = new TemplateProcessor(resource_path('path/to/document.docx'));

 $doc->setValue('random_index1', $data['random_index1']);
 $doc->setValue('random_index2', $data['random_index2']);

 $filePath = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), 'PHPWord');
 $tempFile = $doc->saveAs($filePath);
```